# Properly configuring boost in CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have a very simple boost application:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/) {
    if( boost::filesystem::exists(".") )
        std::cout << "exists" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which I configure with CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
set(USE_BOOST_LIB_HACK TRUE)

#--- Boost (TODO: wrong libraries linked)
find_package (BOOST COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
if(USE_BOOST_LIB_HACK)
    #--- Now I need to manually append them to avoid missing symbols
    list(APPEND libs /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.dylib)
    list(APPEND libs /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.dylib)
else()
    list(APPEND libs ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) 
    message(STATUS BOOST: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) #<<< EMPTY :( :(
endif()

#--- Add all sources in this folder
file(GLOB_RECURSE hdrs "*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE srcs "*.cpp")

#--- Create executable and link
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
add_executable(boost ${hdrs} ${srcs})
target_link_libraries(boost ${libs})
```

Note tha hack `USE_BOOST_LIB_HACK` in the file above. But shouldn't `Boost_LIBRARIES` have what I need? In the configure above it's a trivial empty string. I am using {cmake,boost1.5} from **OSX/Homebrew**

Is my configuration somehow incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: I would add a minimal boost version to require: `find_package(Boost 1.50 COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)`

Comment: Tried that, no difference. I don't get it, the headers are found and reported, but the libraries are not. Although they clearly exist as you can see in my cmake file above (which compiles flawlessly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMake is case-sensitive. Use `find_package(Boost ...)` but not `find_package(BOOST ...)`.
BTW `COMPONENTS` suboption is optional if `REQUIRED` used:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED filesystem system)
```

- Possible explanation: http://pastebin.com/qQyGnQDL

Comment: To clarify: It is not CMake that causes trouble here but the file system. CMake itself does not care about case at all, but `find_package` will attempt to open a find script of the queried name on the file system. So in Windows the all-caps version will probably still work, on Linux it will probably fail and on OS X it depends on how you configured your HFS partition. That being said, your correction is completely valid and the only way to get a portable script that works correctly everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @ruslo, indeed that was the problem!! I am running OSX10.9 on a *case unsensitive* partition. It's unbelievable that cmake doesn't have something to give you a meaningful error!!

Comment: @ruslo Indeed, the all-caps call seems to drop the `REQUIRED` parameter along the way. I'm not sure what is causing this behavior (both calls end up executing the same find script), but it sure is some interesting behavior.

Comment: @ruslo Right, the problem seems to be the way [`find_package`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) generates certain variables for the find script it invokes based on the package name. Since variable names in CMake are case-sensitive, that's what causes the check for the `REQUIRED` parameter to fail. Interestingly, this gives the find script a way to detect whether it was invoked with the correct case and fail with a corresponding error even on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the documentation from `FindBoost.cmake` describes proper usage of the macro:

```
#
#   set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
#   set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
#   set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
#   find_package( Boost 1.36.0 COMPONENTS date_time filesystem system ... )
#
#   if(Boost_FOUND)
#      include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#      add_executable(foo foo.cc)
#      target_link_libraries(foo ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
#   endif()
```

And this method works well on Linux indeed. But I'm not sure about MacOSX/HomeBrew, although it's not mentioned specifically in the macro.

Comment: Hi there, I tried exactly what's reported above. Same as before, I do get the "-- Boost version: 1.55.0" in output of cmake but my ${Boost_LIBRARIES} is still empty...

My boost installation is under /usr/local/{lib,include}